# Why does my lock-free message queue segfault :(?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, lock-free

As a purely mental exercise I'm trying to get this to work without locks or mutexes. The idea is that when the consumer thread is reading/executing messages it atomically swaps which `std::vector` the producer thread uses for writes. Is this possible? I've tried playing around with thread fences to no avail. There's a race condition here somewhere because it occasionally seg faults. I imagine it's somewhere in the `enqueue` function. Any ideas?

```
// should execute functions on the original thread
class message_queue {
public:
    using fn = std::function<void()>;
    using queue = std::vector<fn>;

    message_queue() : write_index(0) {
    }

    // should only be called from consumer thread
    void run () {
        // atomically gets the current pending queue and switches it with the other one
        // for example if we're writing to queues[0], we grab a reference to queue[0]
        // and tell the producer to write to queues[1]
        queue& active = queues[write_index.fetch_xor(1)];
        // skip if we don't have any messages
        if (active.size() == 0) return;
        // run all messages/callbacks
        for (auto fn : active) {
            fn();
        }
        // clear the active queue so it can be re-used
        active.clear();
        // swap active and pending threads
        write_index.fetch_xor(1);
    }
    void enqueue (fn value) {
        // loads the current pending queue and append some work
        queues[write_index.load()].push_back(value);
    }
private:
    queue queues[2];
    std::atomic<bool> is_empty; // unused for now
    std::atomic<int> write_index;


};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    message_queue queue{};
    // flag to stop the message loop
    // doesn't actually need to be atomic because it's only read/wrote on the main thread
    std::atomic<bool> done(false);
    std::thread worker([&queue, &done] {
        int count = 100;
        // send 100 messages
        while (--count) {
            queue.enqueue([count] {
                // should be executed in the main thread
                std::cout << count << "\n";
            });
        }
        // finally tell the main thread we're done
        queue.enqueue([&] {
            std::cout << "done!\n";
            done = true;
        });
    });
    // run messages until the done flag is set
    while(!done) queue.run();
    worker.join();
}
```

Comment: If you're interested, check out a lock-free, single producer, single consumer, bounded queue I wrote a few years ago https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5dz14dTy7VgMWRhYTgyZjctNjI2MS00MjdjLWJmZDEtNDg2OTI1NjA5NDRj/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NickStrupat Thanks that's very useful! I was also looking at the ProducerConsumerQueue included in Facebook's Folly library. My main problem is I'd like a non-fixed buffer size for messages (this is for something akin to `window.postMessage` but for C++ threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lock-free queue fails to work because you did not start with at least a semi-formal proof of correctness, then turn that proof into an algorithm with the proof being the primary text, comments connecting the proof to the code, all interconnected with the code.

Unless you are copy/pasting someone else's implementation who **did** do that, any attempt to write a lock-free algorithm will fail.  If you are copy-pasting someone else's implementation, please provide it.

Lock free algorithms are not robust unless you have such a proof that they are correct, because the kind of errors that make them fail are subtle, and extreme care must be taken.  Simply "rolling" a lock free algorithm, even if it fails to result in apparent problems during testing, is a recipe for unreliable code.

One way to get around writing a formal proof in this kind of situation is to track down someone who has written proven correct pseudo code or the like.  Sketch out the pseudo code, together with the proof of correctness, in comments.  Then fill in the code in the holes.

In general, proving an "almost correct" lock free algorithm is flawed is harder than writing a solid proof that a lock free algorithm is correct if implemented in a particular way, then implementing it.  Now, if your algorithm is so flawed that it is **easy** to find the flaws, then you aren't showing a basic understanding of the problem domain.

In short, by posting "why is my algorithm wrong", you are approaching how to write lock free algorithms incorrectly.  "Where is the flaw in my proof?", "I proved this pseudo-code correct **here**, and then I implemented it, why do my tests show deadlocks?" are good lock-free questions.  "Here is a bunch of code with comments that merely describe what the next line of code does, and no comments describing why I do the next line of code, or how that line of code maintains my lock-free invariants" is not a good lock-free question.

Step back.  Find some proven-correct algorithms.  Learn how the proof work.  Implement some proven correct algorithms via monkey-see monkey-do.  Look at the footnotes to note the issues their proof overlooked (like A-B issues).  After you have a bunch of those under your belt, try a variation, and do the proof, and check the proof, and do the implementation, and check the implementation.

Comment: Wow thank you for your indepth response. I'm currently reading "Concurrency in Action" and watching talks by Herb Sutter to further my understanding. Do you have any suggested articles/projects I can look into? Thanks again for the time you took to respond even though I'm obviously just getting my feet wet with atomics.

Comment: I marked the other answer correct because technically it answers my question but if I could I'd send you some of my reputation bounty-style for this answer. There should be an option for that!

Comment: @christ Last time I wrote lock free code, I found phd thesises and other academic publications and unpacked them into code.

Comment: In a Moment of Great Clarity (TM). I realized I'm using these queues in a event loop (separate, libuv) anyway so I can just use a bounded size queue and have the producer store messages in a local vector and flush X messages to the queue on every loop (keeping the loop alive until the local buffer is empty). Luckily both boost and facebook/folly have implementations of this already made :D

Answer (score 4):

if I understand your code correctly, there are *data races*, e.g.:

```
// producer
int r0 = write_index.load(); // r0 == 0

// consumer
int r1 = write_index.fetch_xor(1); // r1 == 0
queue& active = queues[r1];
active.size();

// producer
queue[r0].push_back(...);
```

Now both threads access the same queue at the same time. That's a *data race*, and that means *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Ah I see I was thinking about this all wrong and forgetting about registers and temporary variables. Do you think the general idea is feasible though? Maybe using `thread_fence(acquire)` in the producer and `thread_fence(release)` in the consumer to attempt to force some sane order

Comment: Or am I going in the completely wrong direction with this? This is obviously way easier with mutexes but like I said it's more of an educational project than anything. Thanks, your comment really cleared up what I should be thinking about when dealing with atomics though

Comment: @ChrisT: I can speak only for myself. I thing implementing a lock-free unbounded container is very hard, and I wouldn't even start. For educational purposes, I would try to implement simpler data-structures, e.g. lock-free performance counters.

Comment: I should of figured since I couldn't find any unbounded implementations in my search (plenty of bounded though) :(. For anyone else looking the talks by Herb Sutter really helped me understand atomics (sort of haha) and why what I'm attempting probably needs someone who is way way smarter than me :P

Comment: My secondary idea is to have two linked-lists `pending` and `active` which contain equal sized `blocks` of messages. The producer thread atomically increments it's `block pointer` and `index` in that pointer. The consumer thread will only read the producers `block pointer` and consume blocks that are already full (the producer can call `flush` to force a non-empty block to be sent added to the consumer list, which will happen in the destructor, which works for my use case of worker threads posting messages to the main main thread)

Comment: Basically the consumer is eventually-consistent, ensuring that only blocks that will never be accessed again by the reader are touched by the consumer. Not sure if this makes sense though, I have some more research to do!